# How I Fix error Magento 2 ‘Requested Store Is Not Found’?

Tags: magento2, store-view, magento-2.2.5, store-switcher, not-found

I get this message "Requested store is not found" when I want to fix it.

The requested Store Is Not Found situation come up while migrating Magento 2 store to the latest version of Magento.

Comment: Also facing the issue with some on my magento websites. I suspect from my side a cache issue, because after refreshing the page once the error is gone, and it's happening almost everytime after we deploy a new version. I suspect a flat table not being written fast enough. Sorry, not very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the following query in your database, and then try to open the website.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```